# raspberry pi + maven + jdk1.8 + javafx

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a JavaFx application that have to run on a raspberry PI.
I followed all the steps to install jdk1.8 on Raspberry, downloaded maven 3.1.1 and copied the project on my raspberry.

When I run

```
mvn clean package
```

the build succeeds, but when I run the command

```
java -cp app.jar my.main.class
```

As described here (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi#OpenJFXontheRaspberryPi-RunningaJDKEarlyAccessbuildontheRaspberryPi)

I receive this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
    at com.ilgala.dmp.components.Playlist.createPlayer(Playlist.java:78)
    at com.ilgala.dmp.components.Playlist.initPlaylist(Playlist.java:55)
    at com.ilgala.dmp.components.Playlist.<init>(Playlist.java:44)
    at com.ilgala.dmp.videoPlayer.VideoPlayer.<init>(VideoPlayer.java:28)
    at com.ilgala.dmp.App.start(App.java:44)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:331)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$RunnableEvent.dispatch(LensApplication.java:182)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication._runLoop(LensApplication.java:861)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication.access$1700(LensApplication.java:58)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$4.run(LensApplication.java:914)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
Exception running application my.app
```

Can anyone help me? I've included the jfxrt in my `pom.xml`

This is it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group.Id/groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact.Id</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>App</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.ilgala.dmp.App</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>com.oracle</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>javafx</includeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/path/to/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use Java 8 for a real project yet. You specified your project as Java 7 in your pom anyway. Why would you use Java 8 as your runtime environment?

Comment: Well, i followed the guide i've found on Oracle JavaFx page, that's why i'm using that one. Raspberry has already JDK1.7.0_40 i should use that one so?

Comment: I can't imagine why they would recommend an early access build. I would use Java 7 for productive use. Although this might not be related to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly look at http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/

The Javafx maven plugin: https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin

It is a great plugin for building javafx applications and you can use its command to link jfxrt.jar to the maven build:

```
mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath
```

Here is the description of the command: http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/fix-classpath.html

I also quote:

> If you don't want to use the fix-classpath Maven command or have
>   problems when running it. You can try manually moving the JAR file
>   yourself from the lib directory to the ext directory. There is no more
>   magic required than that.

Comment: I get this error with the zenjava plugin, running it with maven 3.0.5 on the raspberry:
Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath failed: Plugin com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.7 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar

Comment: @IIGala It's a bug, get 2.0-SNAPSHOT to fix it: https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/27

Comment: Done, a lib folder on the jvm folder was missing then the plugin worked. Now the raspberry seems to do what i need, thanks everyone!